# Two TikZ pictures on the same line with mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, mdframed

I'm looking to get two images besides each other in the same frame. This is what I want to make:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeAEf.png]

I have this:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[lmargin=.5in, rmargin=1.5in, marginpar=1.3in]{geometry} 
    \geometry{letterpaper} 
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,tkz-euclide}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
    \lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=blue,

    \newenvironment{Background2}[0]
        { \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=purple!20,
       hidealllines=true,
       leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=7.5cm
    ]}
        {  \end{mdframed}}


    }
    \begin{Background2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        >=stealth',
        dot/.style = {
          draw,
          fill = white,
          circle,
          inner sep = 0pt,
          minimum size = 4pt
        }
\begin{document}
      ]
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
      \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$x$}] (xmax);
      \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) coordinate[label = {right:$f(x) \ \ \cdot m>0 \text{ then the line goes upwards}$}] (ymax);
      \path[name path=x] (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7);
      \path[name path=y] plot[smooth] coordinates {(-0.3,2) (2,1.5) (4,2.8) (6,5)};
      \scope[name intersections = {of = x and y, name = i}]
        \fill[gray!50] (i-1) -- (i-2 |- i-1) -- (i-2) -- cycle;
        \draw      (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7) node[pos=0.8, below right] {\large \ \ \  $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}>0$};
        \draw (i-1) node[dot, label = {above:$f(x_0)$}] (i-1) {} -- node[left]
          {} (i-1 |- O) node[dot, label = {below:$x_0$}] {};
        \path (i-2) node[dot, label = {above:$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x_0+\Delta x)$}] (i-2) {} -- (i-2 |- i-1)
          node[dot] (i-12) {};
        \draw           (i-12) -- (i-12 |- O) node[dot,
                                  label = {below:$x_0 + \Delta x$}] {};
        \draw[blue, <->] (i-2) -- node[right] {\large $\Delta y>0$}
                                  (i-12);
        \draw[blue, <->] (i-1) -- node[below] {\large $\Delta x>0$} (i-12);
        \path       (i-1 |- O) -- node[below] {$\Delta x$} (i-2 |- O);
      \endscope
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{Background2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately your code is not compileable without the preamble. Please provide a compileable minimal working example so that people can reproduce the current state of your output.

Comment: changed it now.

Comment: Your code is pretty messed up. packages are loaded twice etc. If you remove all unnecessary parts it's more likely that people will work out a solution to your question.

Comment: No, you didn't. A LaTeX document needs some `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Can you try out your code before uploading it here?

Comment: now it should be good.

Comment: Nope. Try out your code before uploading it. Remove all packages that are not used here.

Comment: i use them other places in my document.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not work, at least on my machine. You do not need `mdframed` to shaded the background of a `tikzpicture`, this can be done with the `backgrounds` library.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=.5in, rmargin=1.5in, marginpar=1.3in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    >=stealth',
    dot/.style = {
      draw,
      fill = white,
      circle,
      inner sep = 0pt,
      minimum size = 4pt
    },
    background rectangle/.style={fill=purple!20},
    show background rectangle
  ]
  \begin{scope}
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$x$}] (xmax);
   \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) coordinate[label = {right:$f(x) \ \ \cdot m>0 \text{ then the line goes upwards}$}] (ymax);
   \path[name path=x] (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7);
   \path[name path=y] plot[smooth] coordinates {(-0.3,2) (2,1.5) (4,2.8) (6,5)};
   \begin{scope}[name intersections = {of = x and y, name = i}]
     \fill[gray!50] (i-1) -- (i-2 |- i-1) -- (i-2) -- cycle;
     \draw      (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7) node[pos=0.8, below right] {\large \ \ \  $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}>0$};
     \draw (i-1) node[dot, label = {above:$f(x_0)$}] (i-1) {} -- node[left]
       {} (i-1 |- O) node[dot, label = {below:$x_0$}] {};
     \path (i-2) node[dot, label = {above:$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x_0+\Delta x)$}] (i-2) {} -- (i-2 |- i-1)
       node[dot] (i-12) {};
     \draw           (i-12) -- (i-12 |- O) node[dot,
                               label = {below:$x_0 + \Delta x$}] {};
     \draw[blue, <->] (i-2) -- node[right] {\large $\Delta y>0$}
                               (i-12);
     \draw[blue, <->] (i-1) -- node[below] {\large $\Delta x>0$} (i-12);
     \path       (i-1 |- O) -- node[below] {$\Delta x$} (i-2 |- O);
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$x$}] (xmax);
   \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) 
   coordinate[label = {right:$f(x) \ \ \cdot m>0 \text{ then the line goes downwards}$}] (ymax);
   \path (0.3,4) -- (6.7,-0.2) coordinate[pos=0.3] (x-1)
   coordinate[pos=0.7] (x-2) ;
   \fill[gray!50] (x-1) -- (x-1 |- x-2) -- (x-2) -- cycle;
   \draw (0.3,4) -- (6.7,-0.2)
   node[pos=0.15, above right,font=\large] {$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}<0$};
   \draw (x-1) node[dot](d1){} -- (x-1|-O) node[dot,label=below:$x_0$]{}
   (x-2) node[dot](d2){} -- (x-2|-O) node[dot,label=below:$x_0+\Delta x$]{};
    \draw[blue, <->] (x-2|-x-1) -- node[right,font=\large] {\large $\Delta y<0$}
                                (d2);
    \draw[blue, <->] (d1) -- node[above,font=\large] {$\Delta x>0$} (x-2|-x-1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, there are many ways one can improve the code inside the `tikzpicture`. The following has a few suggestions but is not fully optimized.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=.5in, rmargin=1.5in, marginpar=1.3in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    >=stealth',
    dot/.style = {
      draw,
      fill = white,
      circle,
      inner sep = 0pt,
      minimum size = 4pt
    },
    background rectangle/.style={fill=purple!20},
    show background rectangle
  ]
  \begin{scope}
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$x$}] (xmax);
   \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) coordinate[label = {right:$f(x) \ \ \cdot m>0 \text{ then the line goes upwards}$}] (ymax);
   \path (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7)   coordinate[pos=0.25] (i-1)   coordinate[pos=0.7] (i-2) ;
   \fill[gray!50] (i-1) -- (i-2 |- i-1) -- (i-2) -- cycle;
   \draw      (0.3,0.5) -- (6.7,4.7) node[pos=0.8, below right,font=\large]
    {$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}>0$};
   \draw (i-1) node[dot, label = {above left:$f(x_0)$}] (i-1) {} -- node[left]
     {} (i-1 |- O) node[dot, label = {below:$x_0$}] {};
   \path (i-2) node[dot, label = {above left:$f(x_0+\Delta x)$}] (i-2) {} -- (i-2 |- i-1)
     node[dot] (i-12) {};
   \draw           (i-12) -- (i-12 |- O) node[dot,
                             label = {below:$x_0 + \Delta x$}] {};
   \draw[blue, <->] (i-2) -- node[right,font=\large] {$\Delta y>0$}
                             (i-12);
   \draw[blue, <->] (i-1) -- node[below,font=\large] {$\Delta x>0$} (i-12);
   \path       (i-1 |- O) -- node[below] {$\Delta x$} (i-2 |- O);
  \end{scope}
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$x$}] (xmax);
   \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) 
   coordinate[label = {right:$f(x) \ \ \cdot m<0 \text{ then the line goes downwards}$}] (ymax);
   \path (0.3,4) -- (6.7,-0.2) coordinate[pos=0.3] (x-1)
   coordinate[pos=0.7] (x-2) ;
   \fill[gray!50] (x-1) -- (x-1 |- x-2) -- (x-2) -- cycle;
   \draw (0.3,4) -- (6.7,-0.2)
   node[pos=0.15, above right,font=\large] {$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}<0$};
   \draw (x-1) node[dot,label=above right:$f(x_0)$](d1){} 
   -- (x-1|-O) node[dot,label=below:$x_0$]{}
   (x-2) node[dot,label=above right:$f(x_0+\Delta x)$](d2){} -- (x-2|-O) node[dot,label=below:$x_0+\Delta x$]{};
    \draw[blue, <->] (d1) -- node[left,font=\large] {$\Delta y<0$}
                               (x-2-|x-1);
    \draw[blue, <->] (d2) -- node[below,font=\large] {$\Delta x>0$} (x-2-|x-1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! New to to it so still trying to improve! any specifics you would point out?

Comment: @AndersJensen For instance, use `font=\large` instead of adding `\large` to the node contents. Also I do not see why it is necessary to determine the points on the line by intersections. Just look at the right subpicture.